# Alerta "El plugin no se pudó eliminar por completo."

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

He creado un plugin que estoy testeando y todo funciona adecuadamente, no obstante cuando lo elimino me aparece el mensaje de que no se pudo eliminar por completo.

Buscando por el codex he visto que hay una función para registrar el hook uninstall:

```
register_unsintall_hook('nombre_de_archivo_donde_se_encuentra_la_funcion_uninstall', 'nombre_de_la_funcion_uninstall')
```

Pero por mucho que la aplico no funciona, así que no entiendo muy bien. Y he buscado en otros plugins como `akismet` pero no tiene esta función en ninguna parte ni nada parecido. Ya no se que pensar.

**Actualización 1**: He arreglado lo que comento en la parte superior, el error era que la función donde lo he registrado, tenia mal escrito el hook de inicio. Ahora no me sale el alert, así que genial, pero no me desaparece el plugin, se queda ahí pintado en estado de borrando y hay que refrescar la web. Sabéis si existe alguna función para esto?

**Actualización 2**: He revisado el archivo log que me crea y no me da demasiada información. Tengo un argumento obsoleto en la función load_plugin_textdomain y 9 puntos en stack trace. Pero ningún warning ni nada parecido. Eso si, cuando he accedido a los post type page, en la parte de administración de wordpress, me salen unas tablas con warnings, y además me muestra las entradas y no las paginas. Al entrar en esta pagina (admin page) el archivo log me ha sacado los siguientes errores, que son los mismos que aparecen en las tablas de la pagina de administración de paginas:
1. ( ! ) Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/vagrant/code/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 517 
2.( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: orderby in /home/vagrant/code/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php on line 138

El punto 2 es posible que venga de una duda que tengo que posteada aquí: [Filtro para tabla admin de un custom post no funciona correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171611/filtro-para-tabla-admin-de-un-custom-post-no-funciona-correctamente) ya que si lo comento no me da ningún error. 
Pero no me ayuda ni soluciona nada el comentar el código del punto 2 para que refresque el estado del plugin y este desaparezca por completo.

**Actualización 3: He arreglado ya todos estos problemas que me decia el log y los que anteriormente he comentado. Ya no da ningún tipo de error en absoluto, pero cuando lo elimino el plugin me sigue saltando esta alerta, miro la carpeta y esta vacia. ¿Qué puede ser?**

Una ayudita estaría genial, por favor.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.
**P.D.: Wordpress lo tengo activado en modo debug y también en debug_log**

Comment: Resulta que no se puede eliminar porque tengo una carpeta .git dentro del plugin.
Gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

¿sobre que plataforma lo estas creando? Puede que sea un problema de permisos?

Revisa que `apache` o tu usuario (si estas usando `PHP-FPM`) tengan permisos de edición sobre la carpeta de plugins, así como sobre todos los ficheros y carpetas del plugin en cuestión.

Si aún con eso no se está eliminado, por favor, facilita el error log de `apache` para poder ver que otro problemas estas teniendo.

Comment: De momento lo estoy desarrollando en una maquina vagrant en local y tengo todos los permisos, así que miraré el log como me sugieres. Haber si me puede esclarecer algo.    Gracias por tu ayuda!! :)

Comment: He revisado el archivo log que me crea y no me da demasiada información. Tengo un argumento obsoleto en la función load_plugin_textdomain  y 9 puntos en stack trace. Pero ningún warning ni nada parecido.
Eso si, cuando he accedido a los post type page, en la parte de administración de wordpress, me salen unas tablas con warnings, y además me muestra las entradas y no las paginas.

Comment: Las warnings son:
1. ( ! ) Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/vagrant/code/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 517
2.( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: orderby in /home/vagrant/code/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php on line 138

El punto 2 es posible que venga de una duda que tengo que postee aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171611/filtro-para-tabla-admin-de-un-custom-post-no-funciona-correctamente

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con la información para que esté en un único lugar. También pon Wordpress en modo `debug` a ver si de ahí puedes sacar algo más.